# Can an open id connect id token be used to authenticate to an api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, openid-connect

I am building a mern application.

the backend built using express exposes an api which users can create data and access the data they have created.

I want to allow users to sign in with google and get authorization to create and access the resources on this api which i control (not on google apis).

I keep coming across oauth 2 / open id connect articles stating that an Id token is for use by  a client and a access token provided by a resource server should be used to get access to an api.
e.g. https://auth0.com/blog/why-should-use-accesstokens-to-secure-an-api/

the reason stated for this is that the aud property on the id token wont be correct if used on the api.

I realise that some sources say: that if the spa and api are served from same server and have same client id and therefore audience I can use and id token to authenticate to the api, but I am looking to understand what I can do when this is not the case?

I feel using oauth2 for authorization is overkill for my app and I cant find any information about how to use open id connect to authenticate to my api.

Surely when you sign in to Auth0 authourization server using google it is just requesting an open id connect id token from google?

I am wondering if using Authorization Code Grant flow to receive an id token on the api server would allow me to authenticate a user to my api?

in this case would the api server be the client as far as open id connect is concerned and therefore the aud value would be correct?

I can generate an url to visit the google oauth server using the node googleapis library like so:

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");

const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    'clientid','clientsecret',
    "http://localhost:3000/oauthcallback",//this is where the react app is served from
);

const calendar = google.calendar({ version: "v3", auth: oauth2Client });


const scopes = ["openid"];

const url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
  // 'online' (default) or 'offline' (gets refresh_token)
  access_type: "offline",
  // If you only need one scope you can pass it as a string
  scope: scopes,
});

async function getUrl(req, res) {
  console.log(url)
  res.status(200).json({
    url,
  });
}
```

and use the following flow.

[image]

Comment: That depends on the actual authentication. Suppose jwt is used (which is often the case) but symmetric key is used for signing. This is perfectly safe for authentication. But the client could possibly forge tokens on its own to query resources at the server. This opens a security hole.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to access any API's using the ID-Token. First of all the life-time of the ID-token is very short, typically like 5 minutes.

You should always use the access-token to access API's and you can using the refresh token get new access-tokens. The ID-token you can only get one time and you use that to create the local user and local cookie session.

If you are using a SPA application, you should also consider using the BFF pattern, to avoid using any tokens in the SPA-Application
see [The BFF Pattern (Backend for Frontend): An Introduction](https://blog.bitsrc.io/bff-pattern-backend-for-frontend-an-introduction-e4fa965128bf)

I agree with one of the commenters that you should follow the principle of separation of concern and keep the authorization server as a separate service. Otherwise it will be a pin to debug and troubleshoot when it does not work.

Comment: i am not looking to use an id token, as an access token, i am looking to use the id token (which has been delivered directly to api server by google) to autheticate to the api. i then want to send the client a jwt (not the id token but one i create on my api server same as you would if the logged in with username and password) to use to access the api.


you say i can use id token to create local user and local cookie session. are you refering to an id token which was delivered by 3rd party id provider to the server or to the client?

Comment: The ID-token you receive as a user after authentication is meant to identify the user and typically you create the local session based on that.  You can't use the ID-token to authenticate to an API. So when you authenticate with Google, you should get two tokens back, the ID and access token.

Comment: I want to clarify something: I want to give users access to an api I control. When you mention getting an access token from google I am wondering if you think I am trying to access a google api.
Also you mention creating a local session, is it not implicit in there being a session that the user is authenticated, as a session identifies from whom requests come?

Comment: I assume you use Google to authenticate your users? and when a user authenticates, you should get back an id and access token. Depending on how you configured Google, I assume you can add your API to Google, so that the access token can be used to access the API? if not, you need to add someone else between your API and google, like https://auth0.com/, so they can let users login via Google, and then issue access tokens that your API can accept.

Comment: I am using auth0 successfully on my app at the moment, but would like to figure out how to implement without them.  If you cant use an id token outside of a client then how do auth0 identify a user when they sign in with google, are they not just asking google for an id token?

Comment: In my flow in the question I am not sending an id token from the client to my api, I am requesting the id token directly to the api. That way it has been sent there directly by google. my hope being that the api is then the client and the aud property on the id token is correct.

Comment: What you're pondering here is to make your API also an Authorization Server. It is technically possible to do it, and it would work as you described, but I would discourage you from going that path. It's better to have clear separation of concerns - have the AS issue tokens and API consume them. If you don't want to use auth0, you can setup your own server, e.g. use Keycloak, build with Spring Security, or use the free community edition of our [Curity Identity Server](https://curity.io/product/community)